# JSON with multiple different object's

Tags: c#, .net, json

How can I create JSON file that contains couple different objects without similarity between them? For example 1st object describe some company  (name, net worth, country) and 2nd describes animal (name, specie, jump height)?

Is there any way it can be putted in one JSON file together? It's part of my recruitment task so I can't go other way (I'd love to).

I'm using .NET and C#

Comment: Can't go other way? What does that even mean? What have you tried?

Comment: Surely, there is no restriction on what data structure you can put in JSON. You may very well represent a different kind of objects into one JSON structure.

Comment: Is the point of the task to see if *you* can do it or to see if you can get *someone else* to do it for you?

Answer (score 3):

You can just return nested objects from whatever method you're calling. You will actually have to go out of your way to do this incorrectly. It should serialize itself and return json.

```
class ReturnObject
{
    public List<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public List<Animals> Animals { get; set; }
}

class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal NetWorth { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

class Animals
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Species { get; set; }
    public float JumpHeight { get; set; }
}

public IHttpActionResult GetCompanyAnimals(object objectName) 
{
    Animal animal = new Animal();
    Company company = new Company();
    ReturnObject obj = new ReturnObject();

    obj.Animals.Add(animal);
    obj.Companies.Add(company);

    return Ok(obj);
};
```

Comment: Why not just put each class object into a `List<T>` of type `Object`, then serialize it? Or use `ExpandoObject`

Comment: @RyanWilson yes, that's true. He just didn't mention anything about needing a list.

Comment: @JayJorday Not saying your answer is wrong, just offering other ideas. And I am unclear as to what the OP wants as they haven't bothered to answer any of the comment questions. Also, you may want to modify your answer some to make the returnObject hold arrays of type animal and company for use when pulling down multiple of both types.

Comment: @RyanWilson, I edited to add an example using List<T> so that they can have multiple companies and animals in the return object.

Comment: You're right. I was being kind of lazy.

Comment: Nice job with your answer, thanks for fixing it up some. :)

Comment: Oh my god, thank you. Yeah I was thinking of a list but wasn't sure how to get there. Thanks mate, really appreciate this